# BadHTTPResponse(response.status, text, response) telegram bot api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, urllib3, telepot

I have an inline bot that gets a string from the user(inline mode) and sends back some data.
This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
import telepot

from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from telepot.namedtuple import *
from pprint import pprint
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from mongoengine import connect

from model import *
from setting import *

bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
es = Elasticsearch()
connect('poem')

content_type, chat_type, chat_id = None, None, None

def handle(msg):
    global content_type, chat_type, chat_id
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    pprint(msg)


def on_inline_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_string = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='inline_query')
    print ('Inline Query:', msg)
    response = es.search(
        index="poem",
        body={
            "query": {
                "match": {"text": query_string},
            }
        }
    )
    articles = []
    for index, hit in enumerate(response['hits']['hits']):
        poem = GanjoorPoemModel.objects(id=hit['_source']['poem_id']).first()
        header = u"%s\n%s" % (hit['_source']['poet'], hit['_source']['book'])
        if len(poem.sub_book):
            for sub in poem.sub_book:
                header += u"\n%s" % sub
        header += u"\n----\n"
        link = poem.link
        text = header + poem.text
        if len(text) > 4096:
            temp = poem.text[:(4096-len(header)-len(link)-10)] + "\n" + link
            text = header + temp
        print "A", str(poem.link)
        # text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        iqra = InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(index) + "_" + hit['_source']['poem_id'],
            title=u"%s-%s" %(hit['_source']['poet'], hit['_source']['book']),
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                message_text=text
            ),
            description=hit['_source']['text'],
            thumb_url='https://appreview.ir/wp-content/uploads/com.example.mohammad.books_.png'
        )
        articles.append(iqra)
    bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles, cache_time=5)

def on_chosen_inline_result(msg):
    result_id, from_id, query_string = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='chosen_inline_result')
    print ('Chosen Inline Result:', result_id, from_id, query_string)

MessageLoop(bot, {'inline_query': on_inline_query,
                  'chosen_inline_result': on_chosen_inline_result}).run_as_thread()
print ('Listening ...')

# Keep the program running.
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

In above code when i send to bot a word (like `پروانه`) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/loop.py", line 37, in run_forever
    self._handle(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/helper.py", line 1031, in route
    return fn(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 63, in on_inline_query
    bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles, cache_time=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 868, in answerInlineQuery
    return self._api_request('answerInlineQuery', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 435, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 137, in request
    return _parse(r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 116, in _parse
    raise exception.BadHTTPResponse(response.status, text, response)
BadHTTPResponse: Status 413 - First 500 characters are shown below:
```

when i change the line `bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles, cache_time=5)` to `bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles[:-4], cache_time=5)` this problem does not appear and the bot sends back data. when i use `bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles[:-3], cache_time=5)` I get the error again. and when i use `bot.answerInlineQuery(query_id, articles[6], cache_time=5)` (means exactly the new item of the `articles`) the exception does not raises. means probably this newly added item does not have any problem. where is wrong? is there any timeout? or is there any limit on the total `articles` object? all `message_text` in the items of `articles` array are less than 4096 characters. I think this a `urllib3` limit because when I change my code and try to send `articles` with 1000 items with only one character as text, I get this error again.

Comment: Do you only have this problem when you’re sending words with “Arabic” characters (excuse my ignorance, not sure what language exactly that is), or does it occur too when you completely restrict your test input to ASCII?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your response. This is in `persian`. i test with [this](https://pastebin.com/0X9qv5wJ) example. when i send `articles[:594]` i get `TelegramError` that say `Bad Request: RESULTS_TOO_MUCH` but when i send `articles[:595]` i get the same error as in my question `BadHTTPResponse: Status 413`

Comment: @CBroe the size of `articles[:595]` is `4832` and the size of `articles[:594]` is `4824` (in the test example in last comment)

Comment: @CBroe I test the question code with sending `4096` `a` character as text.It works fine so i Think the problem is with persian and unicode characters. what should i do?

Comment: Have you checked their docs to see if they expect any special encoding?

Comment: @CBroe yes there is no limit. it is wiered because when i send a persian 1000 words string as text. it does not have any problem. Means yet i dont know the problem is with encoding or with the size

Comment: It could indeed just be a simple “size” issue - size in bytes, not characters. In UTF-8, characters from the ASCII range take one byte, whereas Persian characters take at least two, likely more. So if they limit the number of _bytes_ you are allowed to send, that would mean the number of actual characters that byte size would allow for would be different depending on whether your text is in English, Persian ... or a mixture of the two.

Comment: @CBroe So How can i get the size of string in bytes?